# mysql unable to display repeated entries in the view

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following table in the maria database

[image]

i am looking for the following output as a view

[image]

I have tried different approaches but it is not working.

Comment: MySQL or MariaDB? Which is it? Give actual, concrete, useful details about your environment and your scenario and your problem. "It is not working" is not acceptable.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1):

Use `group_concat()` to aggregate the ids and do a self join of the table:

```
select t.id, t.name, 
  group_concat(tt.id order by tt.id) repeated
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on tt.name = t.name and tt.id <> t.id
group by t.id, t.name                             
order by t.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2k1kMd9oZYjeNEw1HQBLqT/3).
Results:

```
| id  | name  | repeated |
| --- | ----- | -------- |
| 1   | John  | 4,8      |
| 2   | Smith | 3        |
| 3   | Smith | 2        |
| 4   | John  | 1,8      |
| 5   | Anna  |          |
| 6   | David | 7        |
| 7   | David | 6        |
| 8   | John  | 1,4      |
```

Comment: seems like it is not good query if your data is big also instead of t.name i am using concat for 3 colums to match

Comment: This code answers the question as you posted it. If you have a new requirement you can ask a new question.

Comment: just shared the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023919/mysql-unable-to-display-repeated-entries-in-the-view-and-intial-dataset-is-using